# C# Socket.SendTo() routing to wrong adaptor

Tags: c#, sockets, routes

I have inherited a UDP send/receive application. It allows a network to be selected and then sends/receives data on that network, with the intention that data is broadcast to/received from all devices on the selected network.
Receive works just fine, however when the application sends data it goes to the wrong network.

Frustratingly, it works just fine on the original PC (Windows 7) but fails on the two others I have tried in the same way (both Windows 10).
Updated with minimal working example:

Form1.cs

```
using System;
using System.Timers;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MinimumWorking
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Network m_Network;
        bool m_NetworkStarted;

        System.Timers.Timer m_Timer;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            m_Timer = new System.Timers.Timer(250);
            m_Timer.Elapsed += OnTimer;
            m_Timer.AutoReset = true;
            m_Timer.Enabled = true;
            m_Timer.Stop();

            m_Network = new Network(this);
        }

        private void button_StartNetwork_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (m_NetworkStarted == false)
            {
                if (m_Network.InitNetwork("225.0.0.37", 2031))
                {
                    button_StartNetwork.Text = "Stop";
                    m_NetworkStarted = true;
                    m_Timer.Start();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                m_Network.Close();
                button_StartNetwork.Text = "Start";
                m_NetworkStarted = false;
            }
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            m_Timer.Stop();

            if (m_NetworkStarted == true)
            {
                m_Network.Close();
            }
        }

        private void OnTimer(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            byte[] msg = new byte[] { 0x54, 0x45, 0x53, 0x54 };
            m_Network.SendPacket(new Packet(msg, msg.Length));
        }
    }
}
```

Form1.designer.cs (should I post all of this?)

```
namespace MinimumWorking
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        //Windows Form Designer generated code (not posted)

        private System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox group_Network;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button_StartNetwork;
        public System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox comboBox_Config_Interfaces;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label lbl_Interface;
    }
}
```

Network.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MinimumWorking
{
    public class Packet
    {
        public int m_length;
        public byte[] m_data;

        public Packet (byte[] data, int length)
        {
            m_data = new byte[length];
            Array.Copy(data, m_data, length);
            m_length = length;
        }
    }

    class Network
    {
        Form1 m_form;

        AutoResetEvent m_resetEvent;
        Thread m_readerThread;
        public bool m_receiving { get; set; }
        Thread m_senderThread;
        public bool m_sending { get; set; }

        Queue<Packet> m_MessageQueue = new Queue<Packet>();

        IPEndPoint m_ipEndPointRx;
        IPEndPoint m_ipEndPointTx;
        Socket m_readSocket;
        Socket m_transmitSocket;

        Object m_lock;

        public Network (Form1 form)
        {
            m_form = form;
            m_lock = new object();
            PopulateInterfaces();
        }

        public bool InitNetwork(String ipAddr, int port)
        {
            m_resetEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);

            try
            {
                m_transmitSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
                IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse(ipAddr);

                IPAddress ipIntAddress = IPAddress.Parse(m_form.comboBox_Config_Interfaces.Text);

                m_transmitSocket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.AddMembership, new MulticastOption(ipAddress, ipIntAddress));
                m_transmitSocket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
                m_ipEndPointTx = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port);
            }
            catch (SocketException)
            {
                return false;
            }
            m_sending = true;
            m_senderThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(SendThread));
            m_senderThread.Start();

            try
            {
                m_readSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
                IPAddress ipAddressRx = IPAddress.Parse(ipAddr);

                m_ipEndPointRx = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 2040);
                m_readSocket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
                m_readSocket.Bind(m_ipEndPointRx);

                IPAddress ipIntAddressRx = IPAddress.Parse(m_form.comboBox_Config_Interfaces.Text);
                m_readSocket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.AddMembership, new MulticastOption(ipAddressRx, ipIntAddressRx));
                m_readSocket.ReceiveTimeout = 100;
            }
            catch (SocketException)
            {
                return false;
            }
            m_receiving = true;
            m_readerThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ReadData));
            m_readerThread.Start();

            return true;
        }

        void PopulateInterfaces()
        {
            List<String> interfaces = new List<String>();

            IPAddress[] ips = Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName());

            foreach (var nic in ips)
            {
                if (nic.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                {
                    interfaces.Add(nic.ToString());

                    m_form.comboBox_Config_Interfaces.Items.Add(nic.ToString());
                }
            }
            m_form.comboBox_Config_Interfaces.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }

        public void Close()
        {
            m_transmitSocket.Close();
            m_sending = false;
            m_resetEvent.Set();
            m_readSocket.Close();
            m_receiving = false;
        }

        public void SendPacket(Packet packet)
        {
            lock (m_lock)
            {
                m_MessageQueue.Enqueue(packet);
            }
            m_resetEvent.Set();
        }

        public void SendThread()
        {
            try
            {
                while (m_sending)
                {
                    m_resetEvent.WaitOne();
                    lock (m_lock)
                    {
                        foreach (var message in m_MessageQueue)
                        {
                            if (m_transmitSocket != null)
                            {
                                m_transmitSocket.SendTo(message.m_data, m_ipEndPointTx);
                            }
                        }
                        m_MessageQueue.Clear();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
            }
        }


        private void ReadData()
        {
            byte[] b = new byte[1024];
            EndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
            while (m_receiving)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (m_readSocket.ReceiveFrom(b, ref endPoint) > 0)
                    {
                        // Parse the message
                    }
                }
                catch (SocketException)
                {
                    // Timeout
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

SendTo() returns the data length I would expect, and I can see the data with Wireshark just on the wrong adaptor.

ipconfig output

```
Windows IP Configuration


Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.56.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : lan
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.25
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1

Ethernet adapter Ethernet 2:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.16.15.34
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
```

I have checked that the correct IP Address is being selected. I've also tried setting a static route and unplugging the primary adaptor (the data just doesn't get sent).
Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: The mask of the interface is wrong.  From cmd.exe >IPCONFIG/ALL  check subnet mask.  Routing uses the route with the most restricted mask.  So routing will use mask 255.255.255.0 before 255.255.0.0.

Comment: Without a good [mcve] it's not possible to answer your question. That said, the whole point of multicast is that the datagram is received by any listener on the same channel. The channel's aren't assigned per-adapter, so it's not clear why you expect the datagram to be received on a specific adapter.

Comment: @jdweng Interesting, the interface did indeed has a less restrictied mask. When I changed this mask (I now have 3 interfaces, all with mask 255.255.255.0) data started sending on a different, but still incorrect, interface. Is there anything else which determines interface 'priority'?

Comment: @PeterDuniho Updated with minimal working example (sorry, late evening question). The PCs are connected to two networks, one for general intranet traffic and one for various embedded devices. The intention is that data is broadcast to all devices on one network or the other.

Comment: @jdweng I tried changing subnet masks so that my inteded network is the most restricted, but data was still sent on one of the other two networks.

Comment: I need to see the IP address and subnet of all interfaces.  You may have a bridge and getting data through another device.  Check the TTL of messages which get decremented by one through each hop (server router).  If message is coming through another device you should be able to tell by the TTL.

Comment: @jdweng Posted ipconfig output. TTL (checked on the outgoing packet via Wireshark?) is 1 for all packets.

Comment: What IP are you sending to?  Is it inside of the range of the mask?  TTL 1 is wrong.  when I Ping my PC with IP the TTL is 128.  When TTL is 0 the packet is not forwarded to prevent routting loops.  What is interesting is when I ping either LocalHost or Hostname I do not get a TTL.  I'm not sure but having a TTL of 1 may indicate that you are using DHCP and getting route from a DNS Server.  Check IPConfig/all for settings.  Also capture ping with sniffer using both IP and Hostname to see if TTL is different.  Are you sending using IP or Hostname?

Comment: @jdweng You've lost me there, I don't have a lot of networking knowledge. I'm sending to a broadcast address (via my interface of choice), so I can't ping it. I've managed to fix it with an explicit bind on the tx socket, I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue by explicitly binding my transmit socket to the selected IP Address. My transmit socket init becomes:

```
m_transmitSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse(ipAddr);

IPAddress localIPAddr = IPAddress.Parse(m_form.comboBox_Config_Interfaces.Text);
IPEndPoint localIPEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(localIPAddr, port);
m_transmitSocket.Bind(localIPEndPoint);

m_transmitSocket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.AddMembership, new MulticastOption(ipAddress, localIPAddr));
m_transmitSocket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
m_ipEndPointTx = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port);
```

I still do not understand why this worked without the bind on the original PC, or why changing the subnet mask affected which network was used (see @jdweng comments on the question)

Comment: You never used the variable L:ocalIPEndPoint in original code.  Did it fix the TTL?  Ping is a different protocol (ARP) from UDP and TCP.  So you can ping to make sure there is a route from one IP to another IP.

Comment: Yes I had to create localIPEndPoint and bind to it to fix the problem, it wasn't in the original code. The TTL on the outgoing packets is still 1. If I ping one of the devices on the network the TTL is 64, but I'm not sendings packets to a specific device, rather I'm trying to broadcast them.